# 3 monitors setup on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have Nvidia GT 710 (1gb, DVI, VGA, HDMI) and Intel integrated graphic card (DVI, VGA). I enabled multi monitor mode in BIOS, but I can't get the picture on the 3rd montior, which is on integrated cart.

System see's all 3 monitors (System settings / Displays), but 3rd monitor is grayed.

Nvidia proprietary (384.90) is in use currently, and I have no Intel graphic driver installed (I saw that it's already packed with Ubuntu?).

Comment: 14.04 is very old and there is little to no desktop support. I highly advise you do a fresh install of 17.10 if nothing else the kernel alone, let alone all the changes to ubuntu with the change to systemd and wayland.

Comment: Is this a fresh install ? Were the 3 monitors ever working ?

Comment: some systems can't do three monitors even if they have 3 ports.

Comment: I couldn't update to 16.04 before, there was some error, I can't remember now what it was, but I'll try doing that first.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I ended up buying HDMI to VGA converter, easier and faster than messing with settings, drivers etc.